# iOS UiTextField Limit input causing keybard issue

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I'm trying to limit the amount of characters that a user can input. I have that working, the only problem is it's now stopped the keyboard from closing. For example I want to restrict input to 3 characters, I type two characters and press done on the keyboard the keyboard closes but if I type 3 characters and press done the keyboard doesn't close any ideas as to why?

heres my code

```
 (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"%@", self.chosenTime);
    [self startGame];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.nameTextField.delegate = self;
      NSLog(@"%@", self.playerName);
    NSString *timeString =  self.chosenTime;
    self.timer = [timeString intValue];
    self.timeSelected = [timeString intValue];
    self.scoreTimer = 1000;
    self.countdown.text = timeString;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


- (IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Hello");
    [self.nameTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    self.playerName = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    return !([self.playerName length] >= 4);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, change the last two methods to these three:

```
- (void)hideKeyboardAction {
    [self.nameTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Hello");
    [self hideKeyboardAction];
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    self.playerName = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    BOOL shouldStayOpen = !([self.playerName length] >= 4); 

    if (!shouldStayOpen)
    {
        [self hideKeyboardAction];
    }

    return shouldStayOpen;
}
```

Comment: just one issue is that when i log the values if i type 3 characters and the press another it closes the keyboard but the string is 4 characters long